# pyenv shims are sometimes not executable

Tags: python, aws-cli, pyenv

We are running a pyenv 3.7.8 virtual environment created with `pyenv-virtualenv`. We are reproducibly finding that if we `pip install awscli`, the `aws` binary is not executable. This is on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04.

If we go to the directory indicated by `pyenv which python` e.g., `/home/${USER}/.pyenv/versions/ENVNAME/bin/`, we see:

```
drwxr-x--- 2 user user 4096 Nov  5 11:39 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2239 Nov  5 11:38 activate
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 1291 Nov  5 11:38 activate.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2443 Nov  5 11:38 activate.fish
-rw-r----- 1 user user  866 Nov  5 11:39 aws
-rw-r----- 1 user user 1432 Nov  5 11:39 aws.cmd
-rw-r----- 1 user user  204 Nov  5 11:39 aws_bash_completer
-rw-r----- 1 user user 1187 Nov  5 11:39 aws_completer
-rw-r----- 1 user user 1807 Nov  5 11:39 aws_zsh_completer.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  284 Nov  5 11:38 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  284 Nov  5 11:38 easy_install-3.7
...
```

Of course, `pip[3]`, `python[3]`, `easy_install`, etc. commands are all executable. The issue appears to limited to `aws` itself for some reason we can't figure out.

On macOS latest, the same behavior does not happen: `aws` is installed and executable.

We're unable to track down the behavior difference so far. Is there something in the environment that controls whether the console_scripts for a specific package are executable or not when installed with pyenv?